# tableview custom cell label using storyboard not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am using a custom cell and taking a label on cell using the storyboard.
and referring that label using tag

```
 UILabel *name=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
```

but it causing a crash,crash log is something like:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel contentOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0814b0'

My code for tableview cell is as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellid";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.citytable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        @try{


            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        UILabel *name=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
return cell;
}
```

If I dont take label from using storyboard,it works fine.so what is this **[UILabel contentOffset]:**?

Comment: `UILabel` has no `contentOffset` method. So you have some memory error. Try to set All exceptions breakpoint

Comment: contentOffset is a property of UIScrollView, so you are trying to use the label as a scrollview or any other sub class of it so you are getting this exception. This is not the entire code please update the entire datasource method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App crashes because you are not taking a **UILabel** object for the **name**. May be the view with tag 1 will be a **UITableView**. *contentOffset* is a method of UITableView. So make sure you are not typecasting a *UITableView* to a *UILabel*. You can try with different tag like 1001, 1002,etc also.